# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory -Heroku

Tags: node.js

I'm new in web and just started working on NodeJS.

I have deployed an application on Heroku. But when I was saving my images files on my local machine then it was working great, but when I deployed it on Heroku server then my images are not saving and show me error:
`Error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../public/uploads/1623462977307.png'`

Here is My Code:
[image: Code]

my FILES_PATH is ../public/uploads Set on Heroku env variables.
I tried all like absolute path, relative path but issue is not resolving.

Comment: In the future please post your [code as text and not as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 3):

That error means the `../public/uploads` folder doesn't exist. You can fix the error by making sure the folder exists. Create the folder, put an empty file inside it called `.gitkeep`, and commit the change. This will keep the empty folder in your repository when you push to Heroku.

Keep in mind that Heroku's filesystem is ephemeral/short lived. This means that any images you save on the disk will disappear after you restart or deploy your app. You can't rely on Heroku's filesystem to store images that need to persist for a longer time. Read more here: https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

You're better off saving images elsewhere. Have a look at cloud storage solutions such as Cloudinary or AWS S3.